Convert rgba/hsla over white to not transparent rgb/hsl using css functions
Is it possible to convert rgba/hsla over white to not transparent rgb/hsl using css functions like 'color-mix' or other?
E.g.: rgba(31, 198, 149, 0.5) => rgb(143, 227, 202)


body {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    lightgray 0px 2px,
    white 2px 12px
  );
  --background-primary: rgba(31, 198, 149, 0.5);
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.transparent {
  background: var(--background-primary);
}

.solid {
  /*background: some_function(var(--background-primary)); it's what I need*/
  background: rgb(143, 227, 202);
}
<body>
  <div class="box transparent">
    rgba(31, 198, 149, 0.5)
  </div>
  <div class="box solid">
    rgb(143, 227, 202)
  </div>
</body>




You can use  color-mix() in CSS.

how you are getting/setting the color?

@TemaniAfif I have css var with transparent color. I need to reuse this var but avoiding transparency effect.

then share your code where you have that variable

@TemaniAfif I shared modified code.

are you going to use it only for background?

@TemaniAfif yes.

If it's only about background, I would simply add the white layer below it. Your color becomes a gradient.


body {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    lightgray 0px 2px,
    white 2px 12px
  );
  --background-primary: rgba(31, 198, 149, 0.5);
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.transparent {
  background: var(--background-primary);
}

.solid {
  background: linear-gradient(var(--background-primary) 0 0) #fff;
}
<body>
  <div class="box transparent">
    rgba(31, 198, 149, 0.5)
  </div>
  <div class="box solid">
    rgb(143, 227, 202)
  </div>
</body>




Perfect, thanks!
